# The number of Sylow' p-subgroups of a noncommutative group G of order 28

Tags: group-theory

What is the number of Sylow' p-subgroups of a noncommutative group G of order 28? I've proved that there is only one Sylow' 2-subgroup and 7-subgroup. The intersection of 4 and 7 is identity. Does it mean that the number of that subgroups is 1?

Answer (score 1):

Let first $p = 7$. Then $n_{7}$, the number of Sylow $7$-subgroups of  $G$, has to divide $28/7 = 4$, and be congruent to $1$ modulo $7$, so $n_{7} = 1$, that is, there is only one Sylow $7$-subgroup $S$.

Now consider $p = 2$. So $n_{2}$ is odd, and must divide $28/4 = 7$. 
What are the possibilities for $n_{2}$ then?

**Spoiler 1**

> $n_{2}$ can be $1$ or $7$.

If $n_{2} = 1$, then there is only one Sylow $2$-subgroup $T$, which is thus normal, and it has order $4$. Now what to do you know about groups of order the square of a prime?

**Spoiler 2**

> They are abelian.

Arguing as you were doing, what does this tells you about $G$  when $n_{2} = 1$?

**Spoiler 3**

> $G$ is abelian, as it is the direct product of the abelian subgroups $S$ and $T$.

If $G$ is non-abelian, what is $n_{2}$ then?

**Spoiler 4**

> See **Spoiler 1**.